Java Spring fetch Headers while scanning classes
@ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/all/{hotelId}")
    public List<RoomEntity> allRoomsByHotel(@PathVariable Long hotelId, @RequestHeader(value = "hotelId", required = true) long hotelId2){
        System.out.println("Value of header 'hotelId': " + hotelId2);
        System.out.println("Path variable 'hotelId': " + hotelId);
        List<RoomEntity> allRooms = roomService.allRoomsByHotel(hotelId);
        return allRooms;
    }

So i do have this endpoint with requested header hotelId
and im writing other class that will scan through all classes in project to gather informations about these endpoints including required headers
but when i try something like this
public Set<Class<?>> findAllClassesUsingReflectionsLibrary(String packageName) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName, new SubTypesScanner(false));
        return reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    }

    public Map<Class<?>, Set<EndpointInfo>> findEndpointsInClasses(Set<Class<?>> classes) {
        Map<Class<?>, Set<EndpointInfo>> classEndpointsMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            Set<EndpointInfo> endpoints = new HashSet<>();
            Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(RequestHeader.class)){
                    System.out.println("here!");
                    RequestHeader requestHeader = method.getAnnotation(RequestHeader.class);
                    System.out.println(requestHeader);
                }

its not fetching info, is there any other way to make it work?
I've tried debugging it, but cant find anything about headers in this class.
My other approach
if (method.isAnnotationPresent(GetMapping.class)) {
                    GetMapping getMapping = method.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMapping.headers()));
}

but it just cant fetch it.

Because the method isn't annotated with that annotation, the method argument is. Your method is annotated with @ResponseBody and @GetMapping not @RequestHeader one of the method arguments is.
